# Complexity of a loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

> If the body of a simple for loop has time complexity $O(n)$ and it is
>    executed $n-1$ times what is the time complexity of the complete loop?

I am trying to figure out the correct answer to this question for my upcoming exam. My reasoning is that if the body of the loop is executed $n-1$ times and its complexity is $n$ then the complete loop should have time complexity of $O(n \times (n-1)) = O(n^2 - 2) = O(n^2)$.

However, the correct answer given to us is $O(n^3)$. 
Am I missing something or is it just a mistake in the answers?

**Edit**: It turns out that the answer given to us was just wrong...

Comment: Your question is vague and it requires more detail.

Comment: Geez, who hands out such exercise problems? Learning value near zero...

Comment: Note that O(n²) and O(n³) are not contradictory. Do you want to use $\Theta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the body of the simple loop is run in $O(n)$. As a loop iterates over the body $n$ time (probably), the time complexity of the loop is $O(n^2)$. When you run the loop $n-1$ times, the time complexity would be $O(n^3)$.

Comment: The answer they gave us was just wrong but your explanation is good too so I will accept it as an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Where do you get "a loop iterates over the body $n$ times" from? That's not in the question at all.

Comment: @DavidRicherby as I've mentioned probably! It was just a guess.